# How to Add a "Please wait" progress bar in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a masterPage siteMaster.master and one aspx page name submission.aspx and a user control attachment.ascx. I have a script manager on my master page. Submission page inherits the master page and on submission page the user control attachment.ascx is registered.

I want to add a upadate panel and updateProgress on ascx page so that I can add please wait on my user control on click Event. I tried script manager and script Manager Proxy. Update progress does not worked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009595/progress-bar-in-webform

Answer (score 0):

Have you associated Update Progress to Update Panel?

if not please refer below Code for Example

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
      .....
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Associate update progress Control to Above Panel Using.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"  AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">.....
```